# VSTO PowerPoint Populate Content Placeholder with HTML

Tags: c#, html, sql, vsto, powerpoint

Using VSTO and C#, how can I populate a PowerPoint slide with formatted text (HTML) returned from a SQL Server database table?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "populate"?  PowerPoint can open some (usually very simple) html pages as though they were presentations. And sometimes it can paste simple HTML from the clipboard onto a slide as HTML Formatted Text.

Comment: With VSTO, I am using C# to create a PowerPoint slide.  I have HTML data stored in the database in which I select and am trying to place into a shape (or text placeholder) using a slide template.

Comment: I can't help with VSTO/C# but anyone who can will still need more information, so:  what sort of HTML data?  Tables, bulleted text, images ...?  Perhaps you could post some example/dummy data of the type you want to work with and a screenshot of what you want it to end up looking like in PowerPoint.

Comment: HTML data such as bulleted and highlighted text.

Comment: You'll probably have to write code to parse the HTML and convert any formatting into the equivalent formatting for PowerPoint.  There's no easy way to just paste the text into PPT.